# Displaying input wrong in a 2-digit Calculator program using int 10h BIOS mouse + keyboard

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bios

I am making a mouse operated, 2-digit calculator in assembly. However I am having problems with displaying the input. The program displays the current input just fine, however the column where it's suppose to input it is wrong. Here is the entire code for making the UI :

```
mov ax, 06h ;ENTER GRAPHICS MODE
int 10h

mov ax, 1   ;SHOW MOUSE CURSOR
int 33h

mov cx, 20  ;INITIALIZE MOUSE CURSOR LEFT SIDE
mov dx, 20
mov ax, 4
int 33h

ui:
    mov dh, 1   ;TOP AND BOTTOM INITIAL ROW
    mov dl, 31  ;TOP AND BOTTOM INITIAL COLUMN
    mov al, '#'

    TopBottom:  ;TOP AND BOTTOM BORDER
        mov ah, 02h ;TOP    ;SET CURSOR POSITION
        int 10h
        mov ah, 0eh ;TELETYPE
        int 10h

        mov dh, 14
        mov ah, 02h ;BOTTOM
        int 10h
        mov ah, 0eh
        int 10h

        mov dh, 1
        inc dl
        cmp dl, 49
        jne TopBottom

    mov dh, 2   ;LEFT AND RIGHT INITIAL ROW
    mov dl, 31  ;LEFT AND RIGHT INITIAL COLUMN

    LeftRight:  ;LEFT AND RIGHT BORDER
        mov ah, 02h ;LEFT
        int 10h
        mov ah, 0eh ;TELETYPE
        int 10h

        mov dl, 48  
        mov ah, 02h ;RIGHT
        int 10h
        mov ah, 0eh ;TELETYPE
        int 10h

        mov dl, 31
        inc dh
        cmp dh, 14
        jne LeftRight

    mov dh, 4   ;MIDDLE INITIAL ROW
    mov dl, 32  ;MIDDLE INITIAL COLUMN

    Middle: ;MIDDLE LINE
        mov ah, 02h
        int 10h

        mov ah, 0eh
        int 10h

        inc dl
        cmp dl, 48
        jne Middle

    mov dh, 6   ;CONTENT INITIAL ROW
    mov dl, 34  ;CONTENT INITIAL COLUMN
    mov al, 55  ;7

Content:    ;NUMBERS, OPERATIONS, AND EVERYTHING IN BETWEEN!!! :D
    mov cx, 0

    Num:    ;1-9
        mov ah, 02h
        int 10h

        mov ah, 0eh
        int 10h

        add dl, 3
        inc al
        inc cx 
        cmp cx, 3
        jne num

    add dh, 2
    mov dl, 34
    sub al, 6
    cmp al, 46
    jne Content

    ;PRINTING ADDITION SYMBOL
    mov dh, 6
    mov dl, 44
    mov al, 43

    mov ah, 02h
    int 10h

    mov ah, 0eh
    int 10h

    ;PRINTING SUBTRACTION SYMBOL
    mov dh, 8
    mov al, 45

    mov ah, 02h
    int 10h

    mov ah, 0eh
    int 10h

    ;PRINTING MULTIPLICATION SYMBOL
    mov dh, 10
    mov al, 42

    mov ah, 02h
    int 10h

    mov ah, 0eh
    int 10h

    ;PRINTING DIVISION SYMBOL
    mov dh, 12
    mov al, 47

    mov ah, 02h
    int 10h

    mov ah, 0eh
    int 10h    

    ;PRINTING ZERO    
    mov dh, 12  ;ZERO ROW
    mov dl, 34  ;ZERO COLUMN
    mov al, 48

    mov ah, 02h
    int 10h

    mov ah, 0eh
    int 10h

    ;PRINTING C (RESTART)
    mov dl, 37
    mov al, 99

    mov ah, 02h
    int 10h

    mov ah, 0eh
    int 10h

    ;PRINTING EQUALS SYMBOL
    mov dl, 40
    mov al, 61

    mov ah, 02h
    int 10h

    mov ah, 0eh
    int 10h
```

The code below is the one that displays the input on screen, however the counter doesn't seem to be working. Although I'm adding 1, it adds 2 during the first loop and doesn't add anything to it after. I'm new to assembly so I might be missing or misusing some of the registers. Please help

```
mov bl, 0   ;COUNTER
func:
    mov ax, 0003h
    int 33h

    cmp bx, 0
    je func

    mov ax, 0004h   ;SET THE MOUSE CURSOR
    int 33h

    add bl, 1

    ;COMPARE ROW
    cmp cx, 286
    jl col1

    cmp cx, 310
    jl col2

    ;cmp cx, 334
    jmp col3

    col1:
        cmp dx, 59
        jl seven

        cmp dx, 76
        jl four

        cmp dx, 92
        jl one

        cmp dx, 108
        jl zero

    seven:
        mov al, 55
        jmp input

    four:
        mov al, 52
        jmp input

    one:
        mov al, 49
        jmp input

    zero:
        mov al, 48
        jmp input

    col2:
        cmp dx, 59
        jl eight

        cmp dx, 76
        jl five

        cmp dx, 92
        jl two

        cmp dx, 108
        jl thing

    eight:
        mov al, 56
        jmp input

    five:
        mov al, 53
        jmp input

    two:
        mov al, 50
        jmp input

    thing:
        jmp ui

    col3:
        cmp cx, 334
        jg col4

        cmp dx, 59
        jl nine

        cmp dx, 76
        jl six

        cmp dx, 92
        jl three

        cmp dx, 108
        jl equals

    nine:
        mov al, 57
        jmp input

    six:
        mov al, 54
        jmp input

    three:
        mov al, 51
        jmp input

    equals:
        jmp exit

    col4:
        cmp dx, 59
        jl addition

        cmp dx, 76
        jl subtraction

        cmp dx, 92
        jl multiplication

        cmp dx, 108
        jl division

    addition:
        mov al, 43
        jmp input

    subtraction:
        mov al, 45  
        jmp input

    multiplication:
        mov al, 42
        jmp input

    division:
        mov al, 47
        jmp input

input:
    mov dl, 42  ;SET INITIAL COL OF INPUT
    mov dh, 2   ;SET INITIAL ROW OF INPUT
    add dl, bl
    mov ah, 02h
    int 10h
    mov ah, 0eh
    int 10h

jmp func

exit:  

int 20h
```

Comment: The title is supposed to describe the problem, not just the program you're having it in.  It's still not a great title, but that's because you didn't describe the problem very well.  (See [mcve] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for more useful things to say than "wrong".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> mov bl, 0   ;COUNTER
> func:
>     mov ax, 0003h
>     int 33h
>     cmp bx, 0
>     je func
>     mov ax, 0004h   ;SET THE MOUSE CURSOR
>     int 33h
>     add bl, 1
> ```

You expect to keep a counter in the `BL` register, but you missed the fact that the call to get the mouse position returned the button status in the `BX` register. This inevitably destroys your counter because `BL` is the low 8 bits of `BX`!

You could choose to put this counter in another free register like `BP`:

```
    xor bp, bp     ;COUNTER=0
func:
    mov ax, 0003h
    int 33h
    cmp bx, 0
    je  func
    mov ax, 0004h  ;SET THE MOUSE CURSOR
    int 33h
    inc bp         ;COUNTER+1
```

---

Also note that most BIOS functions you use expect you to specify the display page in the `BH` register. (You don't do this at all!) This is another reason why it is not a good idea to keep the counter in the `BL`/`BX` register.

Comment: Ohhh, I knew I was missing something. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

```
mov bl, 0   ;COUNTER
```

Here `bl = 0` commented to be used as counter

```
func:
    mov ax, 0003h
    int 33h
```

`bx = button state` - this will overwrite the `bl` counter, as `bx` is 16 bit register assembled from `bl` (low 8 bits) and `bh` (high 8 bits).

Overall I don't like that wall of code under that... you should probably think about some formula to calculate that functionality, to have the code a bit more compact. Something like (just guessing your assembler, using MASM/TASM/emu8086 sort of syntax, didn't test with anything):

```
UI_PAD_X  EQU      262
UI_PAD_Y  EQU      44

    ; ds is expected to point to data segment already
    mov   di,OFFSET inputBuffer  ; where input will be written
      ; di will hold pointer for next input storage all the time
input_loop:
    cmp   di,100+OFFSET inputBuffer
    jae   exit     ; full input buffer
    mov   ax, 0003h
    int   33h  ; [x, y] = [cx, dx] (640x200), buttons = bx
    test  bx,bx
    jz    input_loop  ; no button clicked
  ; recalculate [x, y] coordinates into index-like values
  ; deducted coordinates from OP: [262, 44] -> [358, 108]
  ; single button is 24x16
    cmp   cx,UI_PAD_X+(4*24)
    jge   input_loop  ; click way too right (no button)
    sub   cx,UI_PAD_X
    jl    input_loop  ; click way too left (no button)
    cmp   dx,UI_PAD_Y+(4*16)
    jge   input_loop  ; click way too down (no button)
    sub   dx,UI_PAD_Y
    jl    input_loop  ; click way too up (no button)
    ; cx /= 24 (by subtraction, as result is 0..3 only = fast)
    mov   ax,-1
input_loop_dix_by_24:
    inc   ax
    sub   cx,24
    jae   input_loop_dix_by_24
    mov   cx,ax    ; cx = 0..3 (column of click)
    shr   dx,4     ; dx /= 16 = 0..3 (row of click)
    ; dx = row*4 + column -> general index of button clicked (0..15)
    shl   dx,2     ; dx *= 4
    add   dx,cx
    ; dx = 0..15 index of button
    cmp   dx, 13
    je    ui         ; "C" button clicked
    cmp   dx, 14
    je    exit       ; "=" button clicked
    mov   bx,OFFSET buttonLabels
    add   bx,dx
    mov   al,[bx]    ; fetch input character ASCII code
    ; store input into total buffer
    mov   [di],al
    inc   di
    ; output buffer
    mov   dx,(2*256)+42   ; start at [42, 2] position
    mov   bx,1            ; bh = page = 0 and bl=1
    mov   ah, 02h
    int   10h             ; set cursor position
    ; output all characters from inputBuffer (at least one in already)
    mov   si,OFFSET inputBuffer
    mov   ah, 0eh
input_loop_print_buffer:
    lodsb      ; al = [si++]
    int   10h  ; ah=0e, al=char, bh=0, bl=1
    cmp   si,di   ; until whole buffer is printed
    jb    input_loop_print_buffer
    jmp   input_loop  ; wait for next click
```

In data segment some memory has to be set up:

```
buttonLabels:
    db    '7', '8', '9', '+'
    db    '4', '5', '6', '-'
    db    '1', '2', '3', '*'
    db    '0', 'C', '=', '/'

inputBuffer:
    db    100 dup (0)
```

Hmm, it's a bit longer than I wished for, but hopefully it will be simple enough to give you some new ideas, how things can be solved in different way.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for the suggestion. I did think my code was a bit too long and but I didn't know how to make it more compact. That's a great ton of help, thanks!

Comment: @blah you may also add some partial evaluation into that code, if you will add some variables and buffers, depends how exactly you want it, whether you want to evaluate final expression (like "12+3\*4=" would result into 24 (much harder to do correctly), or "12+3\*4=" evaluates after each operation into 15 (+3 at \*) and then 90 (\*4 at =) - allows for ongoing evaluation after each button click, numbers doing `temporary = temporary*10 + digit;`, operation buttons can have specific handlers being either done by `cmp dx,btn_index` `je ...`, or by having table for fn. offsets similar to labels.